# Is there a way to read user input from keyboard for PhantomJS?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS to login website and the captcha has to be inputed manually.
How can I save the captcha image to disk, and then input the captcha by hand in PhantomJS console?

Comment: Save the text .. not captcha rendered text

Comment: There's no text, only image. You have to recognize by yourself(by human) and then submit recognized text.

Comment: Like [this](http://labs.abeautifulsite.net/simple-php-captcha/)  example, easy way make capctha from text in PHP ..

Comment: @matzone, sorry for my poor english.I thinik you didn't get it. I'm not making captcha.

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem, just use the system module in combination with a page.render() and some argument passing to page.evaluate.

```
page.render('pagewithcatpcha.jpg');
page.injectJs('http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js');

var arg1 = consoleRead();

page.evaluate(function (arg1) {
 $('.yourFormBox').val(arg1);
 $('.yourForm').submit();
}, arg1);

function consoleRead() {
 var system = require('system');

 system.stdout.writeLine('CaptchaCode: ');
 var line = system.stdin.readLine();

 return line;
}
```

Comment: Works great, *except* I wasn't able to inject the remote file; instead I used **page.injectJs('jquery.min.js')**

Comment: @AdamAlbright to use a external js use `page.includeJs('http://ajax...jquery.min.js')`, to use from a local use `page.injectJs('myJs.js')` instead, as you do `:)`. This solutions also works great for me, +1!.

Comment: Works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking sounds nearly impossible.

If I were desperate to do something like this I might consider the following approach:

- grab the capture, save to disk as image
- output to the console to tell user image is ready
- use window.setTimeout to wait 30 seconds
- user then edits a text file (e.g. `/tmp/code.txt`) with capture result
- after 30 seconds the callback in window.setTimeout will read `/tmp/code.txt`

It's not pretty. But I can't think of any other way off the top of my head.